# How to get all child from Firebase and add as bookmark on the map

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in Firebase. I need to capture all the latitudes and longitudes that are inside each key and add on the map as marker. I did with the code below but it gives null object reference error. What is wrong?

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.child("uploads").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
       for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        double latitude = postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = postSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        LatLng local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(local).title("New Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(local, 18));
}
```

[image: firebase database]

LogCat

```
08-03 19:57:01.204 27287-27287/com.chico.uploadimage E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.chico.uploadimage.ShowMap$1.onDataChange(ShowMap.java:89)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
08-03 19:57:01.444 27287-27287/com.chico.uploadimage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.chico.uploadimage, PID: 27287
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.chico.uploadimage.ShowMap$1.onDataChange(ShowMap.java:89)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: did you get all the chlid??

Comment: harish, no, the application quits and gives null object reference error, you saw my firebase structure in the link?

Comment: Post the stack dump.  Are you confident `mMap` is not null?

Comment: Please post the entire error from your logcat.

Comment: Bob, It is like this mMap = googleMap;

Comment: I did a test with Log.i and it worked, I received all the data. The problem is after iterator for?   Log.v("log", "" + postSnapshot.getKey()); 
 Log.v("log", "" + postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue() + ", " + postSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use iterator to fetch the data. Its worked for me.

```
 Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotsChat =  dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (dataSnapshotsChat.hasNext()) {
       DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshotsChat.next();
       double latitude =    postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
       double longitude = postSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
       LatLng local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);               
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you refer ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

try this. it will help you.

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("contacts");

Query phoneQuery = ref.orderByChild(phoneNo).equalTo("+918058641661");
phoneQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class); 
    }
}
@Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

i followed this.